# How to handle the flutter widget size compatible to all device?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

Here I'm taking two widgets one is textfield widget and another one is Icon widget both are placed in seperate container. I'm very new to flutter, I dont know how to place two widgets parallely each other with different size. But somehow designed for my mobile but when i run my app on different mobile its widgets are overflowing.Can anybody help me out from this issue. Thanks in advance!!! For More reference see the image given.

[image]

Here is my code

```
Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 10.0, bottom: 4.0, right: 20.0, left: 20.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Material(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        // CONTAINER BACKSIDE SHADOW DEPTH
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                        shadowColor: Color(0xFF90A4AE),
                        //CONTAINER BACKSIDE SHADOW COLOR
                        child: Expanded(
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              prefixIcon: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.search,
                                  color: Colors.pink,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {},
                              ),

                              hintText: "Search for restaurant",
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                            ),
                            onChanged: (input) {
                              print(input);
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      height: 55.0,
                      width: MediaQuery
                          .of(context)
                          .size
                          .width - 120,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            width: 1.0,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Material(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        elevation: 3.0,
                        // CONTAINER BACKSIDE SHADOW DEPTH
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                        shadowColor: Color(
                            0xFF90A4AE),
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.tune),
                          color: Colors.pink,
                          onPressed: () {
                           [enter image description here][1]
                          },
                        ), //CONTAINER BACKSIDE SHADOW COLOR
                      ),
                      height: 55.0,
                      width: MediaQuery
                          .of(context)
                          .size
                          .width - 300,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 1.0,
                              style: BorderStyle.solid),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Check these out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcnP3_mO_Ms

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3WrA4zAaPw

Comment: I'm still confused with aspect ratio. Can you give me little more hint about this? @Uni

Comment: aspect ratio is thee ratio of the width and height of a screen display. For example the ratio of a 1920X1080 monitor is 16:9. With aspect ratio, you can identify if the device is using a tablet or a phone. For example if a device has an aspect ratio of 3:4, you would know that device is a tablet, simply because for every 3 pixels in height, there will be 4 of those pixels in width. Try to imagine it then expand it. You can google "What is Aspect Ratio" or watch a video in Youtube clarifying what it is to further understand what aspect ratio is. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot and the code, I see there are two widgets in a row and the screen is overflown as it couldn't accommodate and show both of them.

There are two solutions:

- To show the row children in the next line automatically if overflown.
- To make the row children scrollable row-wise.

NOTE: `SMLink` is my custom widget. Just used here for demonstration purposes.

#### SOLUTION-1

The simple workaround would be to use the `Wrap` widget instead of the `Row` widget.
The `Wrap` widget simply takes the children who are prone to screen overflow and places them on the next line. You can set the `direction`, `spacing` etc, in addition to the options that `Row` widget can offer. Try it & let me know.

```dart
// By default, it behaves as Row, you can set the direction attribute to Axi.vertical to mimic the Column widget.
Wrap(
      spacing: 8.0,
      runAlignment: WrapAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
      alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
      children:
            [
              SMLink(logo: 'Medium', link: Constants.LINK_MEDIUM),
              SMLink(logo: 'linkedin', link: Constants.LINK_LINKEDIN),
              SMLink(logo: 'facebook', link: Constants.LINK_FAEBOOK),
              SMLink(logo: 'Qwiklabs', link: Constants.LINK_QWIKLABS),
            ],
    )
```

#### SOLUTION-2

From the screenshot, the other way to fix would be by making the row scrollable. This makes UI look consistent in your case. We can use `ListView` widget for this.

```dart
ListView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    children:
        [
              SMLink(logo: 'Medium', link: Constants.LINK_MEDIUM),
              SMLink(logo: 'linkedin', link: Constants.LINK_LINKEDIN),
              SMLink(logo: 'facebook', link: Constants.LINK_FAEBOOK),
              SMLink(logo: 'Qwiklabs', link: Constants.LINK_QWIKLABS),
        ],
)
```

Comment: Please upvote and mark as answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. but my problem here is, I dont want to use listwiew in a row or  To show the row children in the next line automatically. Here I need solution to how to place this two widget with different size parallely and how to give size to each widget(first widget is 3 times greater the size of second widget)

Comment: Try using the `flex` attribute in the `Expanded` widget. Another widget is the `FittedBox` that forces children to fit inside it and give it a width of `MediaQuery.of(cintext).size.width`

Comment: If you try to force-fit the widgets by restricting their size, they own't lookgood to the user.

Comment: thanks @Mohith7548 i solved this issue by using flex widget.